# Spring - resolve dependency at runtime

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data

I write `Spring` app with `Spring Data`. I have two entities: `Customer` and `Merchant`. I also have two corresponding repositories and services: `CustomerRepository`, `MerchantRepository`, `CustomerService` and `MerchantService`. Logic in `CustomerService` and `MerchantService` is very similar, but relates to different repositories (accordingly `CustomerRepository` and `MerchantRepository`). So it looks more or less like this:

```
class Customer {
    // ...
}

class Merchant {
    // ...
}

interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
    // ...
}

interface MerchantRepository extends CrudRepository<Merchant, Long> {

}

class CustomerService {
    private CommonHelper helper;

    void method() {
        helper.commonMethod();
        // ...
    }
}

class MerchantService {
    private CommonHelper helper;

    void method() {
        helper.commonMethod();
        // ...
    }
}

class CommonHelper {

    private CrudRepository repository;

    public CommonHelper(CrudRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void commonMethod() {
        repository.findAll();
        // ...
    }
}
```

I wanted to create third class, let's call it `CommonHelper` to avoid code duplication and put common logic there (actions are the same but use different repositories). But then I need two separate instances with two different repositories. Of course I can just instantiate it using `new`, but is there more `Spring` way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract an abstract class for `CommonHelper` and defines two beans implementing it : one for the Merchant concern and another for the Customer concern.
The interface could be generic to be able to adapt the API type according to the implementations.

For example :

```
public abstract class BaseService<T, K> {

    private CrudRepository<T, K> repository;

    public BaseService(CrudRepository<T, K> repository){
       this.repository = repository;
    }

    T commonMethod(K key){
        T object = repository.findById(key);
        // other processing...
    }
}
```

And implementations :

```
@Service
@Qualifier("customerBaseService") 
public class CustomerBaseService extends BaseService<Customer, Long> {
    public CustomerBaseService (CustomerRepository repository){
      super(repository);
    }
}

@Service
@Qualifier("merchantBaseService") 
public class MerchantBaseService extends BaseService<Merchant, Long> {
    public MerchantBaseService (MerchantRepository repository){
      super(repository);
    }
}
```

Then inject the suitable in CustomerService or MerchantService by specifying the qualifier matching to.

Comment: But then I need two write two separate implementations and thus duplicate the code.